# Styling a Mui Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styling

Is there a way to style a MUI datepicker component without using the inputProps property, but using a class in a scss file instead? That's my code for the datepicker component. i styled the component with inputProps, but that makes my code very long, and I would like to style the component, especially the icon of the calendar with a scss class. I work with React typescript. I would really appreciate your help. Have a nice day

```
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <DatePicker
                value={start_date}

                className={styles.datepicker}
                inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                InputProps={{
                  sx: {
                    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                      color: "white",
                      fontSize: "22px",
                    },
                    "& input": {
                      fontSize: "12px",
                      color: "white",
                    },
                  },
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    size="small"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="standard"
                    className={styles.calendar}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

I changed the color of the icon of the datepicker and styled the component using InputProps. It works but I want to use a scss class